# Wow JS solution to remove bold text not working on Macbook Pro (Google Chrome)

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, animation, wow.js

Wow animation stop text rendering bold in mac book pro chrome

I am using wow.js for on scroll animation. it's showing bold text after complete animation on mac book pro.

Looking for the solution on internet I came through this code.

Here is the solution I applied.

```
.wow.animated { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
```

But it's not working for me.

I used below code after revealing animation, added animation class to the element.

```
.subpixel{ animation: font-weight .0000001s;}
 @keyframes font-weight {0%{}
 100%{ -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
}
```

Above code is changing the code from bold to normal but animates while chainging which looks weired.

Answer (score 0):

Prehaps try animation-direction, update code to:

```
.subpixel{ animation: font-weight .0000001s forwards;}
@keyframes font-weight {0%{}
 100%{ -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
}
```

If its a timing issue as you suggest try

```
.subpixel{ 
   animation: font-weight .0000001s forwards;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
   animation-delay: 2s;
}
@keyframes font-weight {
    0%{}
    100%{ -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
}
```

Untested but this should honor the last frame of the animation and delay the animation untill after this initial animation is completed.
**Could you create a fiddle with the problem so we can test?**

Comment: I already try this, if i do "font-weight" animation fast it complete before the first animation and bold issue remain same. and animation play online once.

Comment: If its a timing issue you could try a animation-delay:1s; or smth

Comment: I've updated my answer, please try if this fixed it. @kapil

Comment: Yes got it, but think about it first font appear bold and after that animate bold to normal. it's look wiered. actually i have added many files and i can't share project with anyone. but i'll try to create fiddle for that. Thanks

Comment: @kapil am willing to help with a usecase if you provide basic dom & styling, could be a representation that mimicks the desired behaviour instead of the actual markup&styling. In certain cases larger chains of animations are more managable with javascript/jquery, are you skilled in those langs?

Comment: @kapil how's the fiddle going?

Comment: Finally I change jquery plugin for that. when I am using scroll reveal js  i face this issue font render issue. now i am using wow and scroll magic jquery plugin for on scroll animation, now it's going perfect. I tried to make a fiddle but in fiddle it's show no issue in scroll reveal js and I can't show you my project. 
Thanks for your concern